# measuring overload of power supply

Tags: sensors

I need to measure overload current flow of my 30VDC 1A power supply. There are lots of current sensing circuit with shunt resistor.One of example circuit is below, but i am not sure about what kind of shunt resistor i should use. Any advise for me?

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Current-sensor-circuit.php

I didn't tried any product yet, i am not sure about what kind of shunt i should use.